# OData call $skip giving ECONNRESET Postman

Tags: filter, postman, odata, acumatica

I am getting an ECONNRESET when doing an API call with `$skip 10` in it. When calling the API without filters the data does pull into my Postman. The ECONNREST is immediate and it doesn't look like any data is pulled

Details:

- This is an OData connection.
- Basic Auth
- Normal Headers:

[image]

Working call https://Dom/OData/foo/stockItems
Also working https://Dom/OData/foo/stockItems?$top=1

Issue call   https://Dom/OData/foo/stockItems?$skip=10&$top=10

ECONNRESET:

[image]

The call is to a Acumatica instance where I am pulling the data

Comment: Could you please add the response to the question?

Comment: The error seems to indicate a server-side issue. To get more information, try also to check for any logs on Acumatica. If it is a development environment, I like to enable Acumatica Trace so that it saves logs to the file system.  Another option is to  use the Acumatica Request Profiler Screen (SM205070). Sometimes even Windows Event Viewer might contain useful details, especially if error is at IIS level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was the General Inquiry had multiple instances of the same field configured. For example, there was a FinPeriodID and a FinPeriodID_2. Trying to filter on either of these caused an ECONNRESET error.

Referencing the duplicated fields in the $select causes no problems. It's just the filter that Acumatica doesn't seem to be able to handle.